# Zonal statistics using rasterstats in Python for each time step in a NetCDF within region shapefiles

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, netcdf, rasterio

Trying to extract zonal information within a shapefile layer that contains district regions, for a monthly time series of raster data stored in a netcdf.

I've so far only been able to extract the average across all time periods for each shapefile (see  below). But really I want the monthly average within each region.

The ultimate aim is to have this in a pandas geodataframe which I can then merge with some attribute data for each region. I'm not very used to working with netcdfs so any suggestions would be helpful! The time dimension within the netcdf is 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

```
#import netcdf data 

with rio.open('/MSLA_all_test.nc') as msla_nc:
    msla_nc_data = msla_nc.read(1,masked=True)
    msla_nc_meta = msla_nc.profile

#import polygons 
region_polys = gpd.read_file('/GADM2_coast_regions.shp')

#Extract pixel values for each polygon : zonal stats
region_value=rs.zonal_stats(region_polys, msla_nc_data, nodata=-999, affine=msla_nc_meta['transform'], geojson_out=True, copy_properties=True, stats="mean")
```

Comment: Gotten a little closer! Now have a list of dictionaries with each dictionary containing all the monthly averages for a region across the 72 timesteps (~650 regions). Is there anyway to extract each value in each dictionary (72 x ~650= ~47,000)?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform time aggregation and resampling using xarray. then apply your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you have an example or resources to link to help improve your answer?